# FORMAT ext4 filesystem from Windows

Tags: windows, ext4

I have a hard drive previously used with a Linux system, with an ext4 filesystem. I would like now to zero out the hard drive from a Windows system.

I understand I can do this using the `FORMAT` command, passing in `/p:0` (or another number for multiple passes); as the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format) for `/p` says:

> `/P:`*<count>* -- Zero every sector on the volume. After that, the volume will be overwritten **count** times using a different random number each time. If **count** is zero, no additional overwrites are made after zeroing every sector.

However, the hard drive doesn't have an assigned drive letter, because Windows doesn't natively support ext4.

**How can I refer to the drive in the `FORMAT` command when it doesn't have a drive letter?**

I can get the object ID using `MOUNTVOL` or Powershell `Get-Volume`, but I can't pass that object ID into `FORMAT`. The following command:

```
FORMAT \\?\Volume{8ab24395-0965-40fc-8cc8-bb7536c9e1dd}\ /fs:ntfs /p:1
```

returns:

> The given volume name does not have a mount point or drive letter.

I am running Windows 10 (non-Insiders), and I do not have WSL installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128448/discussion-between-mokubai-and-gantendo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FORMAT` acts ONLY on filesystems that have a drive letter. You can't really do a full disk wipe with it. You can only wipe partitions, but for a single-partition disk it more or less amounts to the same thing.

So go into the Windows Disk Administrator.
Find the partition (or if the disk is completely empty, make a new partition covering the whole disk) and give it a (quick) format with NTFS or any other Windows-supported filesystem and assign it a drive letter.
After that you can do `FORMAT /p:` as desired.

Or (on the command line) you can use `DISKPART` to create the partition and assign the drive letter.
However the `CLEAN ALL` command in `DISKPART` has the same effect as a 1-pass 0-byte overwrite and it acts on the WHOLE DISK. Don't use it if you only want to wipe a single partition/filesystem!
But since you seem to want a disk-level 1-pass overwrite, this would be the quickest way to do it.